# Showing time elapsed with php

Tags: php, time

I am wanting to show the time elapsed since the time posted for a blog or similiar, I am using php and I am storing the time posted as a unix timestamp but I cannot for the live of me work out how to show the time since it was posted using the stored timestamp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If for example your posted timestamp is:

```
1289735677
```

You can also get the current timestamp by using `time()`, for example.

Then you can take your posted timestamp from the current one:

```
time() - 1289735677
```

In that way you will get the seconds elapsed. Now you can change them to human readable format for example.

See examples on how you can convert seconds to human readable format:

1. http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Seconds-To-Hours-Minutes-Seconds-Words.html
2. http://www.laughing-buddha.net/php/lib/sec2hms/

Answer (score 2):

If your PHP is >= 5.3.0 you can use the [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method.