# PHP MySQL display todays date as Today

Tags: php, mysql, date

I notice on forums that when a topic is today's date, the date is displayed as Today. How do you do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP How to find the time elapsed since a date time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways that could be done.  From a purely MySQL standpoint:

```
SELECT 
    IF(CAST(my_timestamp_column AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE, 1, 0) AS is_today 
FROM ...
```

in PHP,

```
if (date('Y-m-d', $timestamp) == date('Y-m-d')) { ...
```

Again, tons of ways to do this

#### EDIT: More MySQL:

```
SELECT
    IF(
        CAST(ts AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE,
        CONCAT('Today at ', CAST(ts AS TIME)),
        ts
    ) AS fancy_date
```

or some more php:

```
$ts = strtotime($mysql_query_result['timestamp_column']);
$todayStart = mktime(0,0,0);
$todayEnd = mktime(23,59,59);
if ($ts <= $todayEnd && $ts >= $todayStart) {
    echo 'Today at ', date('H:i:s', $ts);
}
else {
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

pseudo code:

```
if date == today then display "Today" else display date
```