# How to get the different time between time from php function 'get_date()' and time stored in table by sql function now()?

Tags: php, sql, time, getdate

Use php and MySQL, I want to get the duration in php code between time obtained by get_date() function and time stored in table by NOW() sql function. How to do this? Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - " . time() . " AS diff");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$diff = $result['diff'];
```

`$diff` will contain the difference in seconds between the mysql server and the webserver

Edit: to get the HH:MM:SS difference

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT TIMEDIFF(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), " . time() . ") AS diff");
```

Comment: @ Flambino: then create the function that return duration in year:month:day:hour:min:sec or does it has any function to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Mysql dates will return as strings in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS'. Use the strtotime($date_from_db) to convert it to PHP date. If you're getting the current date/time do not use the getdate() function go for now() instead. After that, use the same instruction from the link [PHP How to find the time elapsed since a date time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time) .