# Select elapsed time from MySQL

Tags: mysql, time, elapsed

I'm using this query:
SELECT NOW() - date AS elapsed FROM ...

Date column is TIMESTAMP.
It returns 41632 when elapsed time is about 4 hours and 20 minutes.
It's not timestamp.
What is it?

Or is there any better way to get elapsed time and generate with PHP like this:
"2 minutes ago"
"3 hours ago"
"yesterday 22:32"

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a guess, 41632 may be 4:16:32

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time

Answer (score 19):

Use the [TimeStampDiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function

```
  select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), timestamp_column) FROM my_table
```

Comment: `select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), timestamp_column) FROM my_table;`

Comment: @Erik Thanks. I've updated my answer (and marked it CW so feel free to edit)

Answer (score 0):

This will show values like:

```
1 month
6 months
4 years
1 year
12 years
...
```

```
IF (
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, timestamp_column, NOW()) > 0,
   CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, timestamp_column, NOW()), " year", IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, timestamp_column, NOW())=1,"","s")),
   CONCAT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, timestamp_column, NOW()), " month", IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, timestamp_column, NOW())=1,"","s"))
)
```