# Time since pubDate

Tags: php, time, rss

In a new project, I'm working with rss being read by PHP and displayed on a page.
One thing I'd like to do is show how much time has passed since the post was published, but I can't find a way to do so, this is my current code, hope somebody can help me!

```
echo "<div id=\"left\">";
    $rss1 = new DOMDocument();
    $rss1->load('http://www.macfan.nl/macfan.rss');
    echo '<h2>MacFan</h2>';
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss1->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 5;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $date = date('F d', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<p><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></p>';
        echo "<p class=\"small\">$date</p>";
    }
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP How to find the time elapsed since a date time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the unix timestamps;

```
$seconds_between_now_and_then=(time()-strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
```

Then you can see how far it is apart. These below could help you make it more readable for yourself:

```
$minutes_between_now_and_then=$seconds_between_now_and_then/60;
$hours_between_now_and_then=$minutes_between_now_and_then/60;
$days_between_now_and_then=$minutes_between_now_and_then/24;

echo 'Seconds:'.$seconds_between_now_and_then.'<br />';
echo 'Minutes:'.$minutes_between_now_and_then.'<br />';
echo 'Hours:'.$hours_between_now_and_then.'<br />';
echo 'Days:'.$days_between_now_and_then;
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the help, but now just another question, How can I make it say 1-60 minutes and after that 1 hour - 24hours and after that the amount of days?

Comment: if ($hours_between_now_and_then>24){ echo $days_between_now_and_then.' days'; } else if ($minutes_between_now_and_then>60){ echo $hours_between_now_and_then.' hours'; } else { echo $minutes_between_now_and_then.' minutes'; }