# Convert Month Year function to Time Ago PHP

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP How to find the time elapsed since a date time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time)

I have the following which produces MONTH YEAR.

```
<?php echo date('F Y', strtotime($video['Video']['posted_date'])); ?>
```

I'd like this to output to "Time" ago. i.e 3 hours ago, 6 months ago, 2 years ago.
Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks
Andy

Comment: Googled this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/time-ago-function/

Answer (score 1):

```
$now            = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$videoPosted    = new DateTime($video['Video']['posted_date']);
$interval       = $now->diff($videoPosted);

echo $interval->format('%h hours, %m month and %d days ago');
```

Use only if PHP version > 5.3

Comment: +1 simple and clean, using built in php libs

Answer (score 0):

If you use php 5.3+, you are looking for [`DateInterval::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Answer (score -1):

this will help you to calculate date difference: [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

and after that you can convert the result using `strtotime()`

Comment: This is no longer really appropriate, since the introduction of `DateInterval`