# Calculating last login time from database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I currently have a database which contains `last_login` and `last_logout` columns with the datatype set to `datetime`. When a user logs in and logs out of the system, the time is updated in both of those columns.

I would now like to create a notification that informs the user of when they previously logged into the system. I would like to display the answer in hours, for example (23 hours ago or 128 hours ago).

I just can't figure out how to perform calculations in PHP with the values in each of these columns. Please help.

I apologise if this question is hard to understand.

Comment: current time minues last_logout will give you the duration

Comment: as the data is in the db, you can use mysql function TIMEDIFF

Comment: To convert a time difference in "x units ago" format, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2916189/266374

Comment: havn't tried it but googled this http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9368/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in mysql

```
Select TimeStampDiff(HOUR,LastLoginTime,Now()) From MyLoginTable
```

For instance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(LOGOUT_COLUMN, LOGIN_COLUMN)) / 3600) AS TimeDiff
```

should do the trick, will return in seconds the difference and then on PHP side you can convert that in minutes or hours.