# PHP change format of date

Tags: php

Is it possible through PHP to change the format of this date

> Jan 1 1900 12:00AM

to

> 01/01/1990

mm/dd/yyy

Comment: RTFM (I recently learned this acronym and I LOVE IT... It applies to so many questions here)

Comment: I assume you mean "Jan 1 1990" in the first line, and not 1900.

Comment: Why are you interested in this wonky date format? It might mislead the readers. One can't say for sure whether it is in the `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Comment: @Lion if he is only using it in the U.S. it would make sense because most people assume that format here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two functions will help: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

So do this:

```
date("m/d/Y", strtotime("Jan 1 1990 12:00AM"))
```

Answer (score 1):

[See PHP's excellent DateTime classes](https://www.php.net/datetime):-

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y H:ia', 'Jan 1 1900 12:00AM');
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

Or, if you are a fan of one liners:-

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('M d Y H:ia', 'Jan 1 1900 12:00AM')->format('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: I never knew about `DateTime::createFromFormat`... will definitely use this in the future.

Comment: @Ethan Once you start using those classes you'll realise how powerful they are. They make [seemingly complex problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16712277/212940) suddenly [very simple](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16712661/212940).

Comment: I've used DateTime before, just never that method. Any idea if there is any simpler way to do what I did [here](https://gist.github.com/etaubman/5609636)?

Comment: @Ethan I'm not sure it's any simpler https://github.com/vascowhite/TimeAgo/blob/master/TimeAgo.php

Answer (score 0):

You could parse that into a timestamp with [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and then use [the PHP date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` and `strftime` are the easiest to work with.

```
$stamp = strtotime('Jan 1 1900 12:00AM');
echo strftime("%m/%d/%G", $stamp);
```

See [the full `strftime` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) to output your date in any format.

Answer (score 0):

No, because Jan 1 1900 1200AM is never going to equal 01/01/1990. Check you year. But if you want a simple what to convert string to time try this:

```
<?php
$d = 'Jan 1, 1900 12:00AM';
echo date("m/d/y",strtotime($d));
?>
```

I would pass this into a function first that removed the time element and then converts only the data portion.

Answer (score -1):

see the date function:

```
//replace the time() with yours
echo date('m/d/Y', time()); // = 06/06/2013
```

manual: http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Comment: please explain down vote

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume it's because you didn't actually take the input date and parse it. You just didn't the output format part.