# PHP find the time elapsed since a date time inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, datetime, foreach, elapsed

I'm looking fe a solution: i have a foreach loop (of posts) inside a slideshow and i need to retrieve the time elapsed since the publish date. I'm following this thread [PHP How to find the time elapsed since a date time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time) and this is what i've done so far, but it doesn't work, it broke the slideshow or i got an error about $time variabe that can't be re decleared. Could someone help? Thanks.

```
<?php if(count($comments) > 0): ?>
<?php foreach($comments as $comment): ?>
<?php
$authorPicture = $comment['authorPicture'];
$author = $comment['author'];
$image = $comment['image'];
$message = $comment['message'];
$likes = $comment['likes'];
$type = $comment['type'];
$data = $comment['cacheDate'];  
$time = substr($data, 0, -3);   //need to do this to retrieve a correct Unix timestamp
function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );
    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }

   }

 ?>
 <div class="data"><?php echo 'event happened '.humanTiming($time).' ago'; ?></div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php else: ?>
    <h2>There are no comments yet</h2>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? DateTime::diff may help you http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!! I found this example and i solved [look here !!!](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#112368)

Comment: Based on that example,do you how can I remove the dashes from the retrieved date? Thanks

Comment: If you have another question worth it, just create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Clément Malet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2627459/cl%C3%A9ment-malet) to point me in the right direction, [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#112368) helped me to get the solution:

```
<?php foreach($comments as $comment): ?>
<?php
// foreach items
$data = $comment['cacheDate']; // this store a unix value like 1404992204999
// foreach items
<!--  html code -->
<div class="message">
<p class="data"><strong>Published: </strong>
<?php 
    $date1 = $data;
    $date2 = time();
    $subTime = $date1 - $date2;
    $y = ($subTime/(60*60*24*365));
    $d = ($subTime/(60*60*24))%365;
    $h = ($subTime/(60*60))%24;
    $m = ($subTime/60)%60;

    echo $h." hour and " . $m." minutes"; // no need for years and days
?>      
<strong>ago </strong>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<h2>There are no comments yet</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And the final output is like: **Published:** 10 hour and 25 minutes **ago**