# PHP Check time elapsed with alternate time format

Tags: php, time

I can find many examples to help compare and difference times, but only when the time is stored in a timestamp. My time is stored in the format `hh:mm:ss` (e.g. 12:30:02). I need to be able to check if  30 seconds have elapsed. For example if the start time was 12:30:02, and the time is now 12:30:33 then yes its over 30 seconds have elapsed and if the time is now 12:30:31 the 30 seconds have not elapsed.

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean checking time with php or sql ?

Comment: What happens at 23:59:59?

Comment: $lastcheck =  $row["juniper_last_time"];
 $date = strtotime($lastcheck);
 
 
 
 if($date > time() + 7990) {
    echo 'yes';
  
  
  if (0 == $status) {
  
    echo "YES";
 
    } else {
     
 echo "NO";
  
    }

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can supply the entire datetime like `2015-01-01 12:30:02`, then [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is your hero:

```
<?php
$input = '2015-01-01 12:30:02';
if (time() - strtotime($input) > 30)
    echo 'Too old.';
```

`time()` gives you the current time in seconds since the "Unix epoch," and `strtotime()` converts a datetime string into seconds since the epoch.