# get difference return wrong value

Tags: php

I have done a `javascript` code and it works good. This script gets the difference between two dates. Now I want to write this script in `php` language, but it returns wrong values.

**[JSFiddle (js version)](https://jsfiddle.net/10kctkL4/4/)**

I want to achieve this via `php`. This is what I have done so far in `PHP`:

```
$NOW = strtotime("now");
$Time = 151048737944;

function dateDiff($date1, $date2)
{

    $diff = abs($date1 - $date2);

    if (floor($diff / 31536000000)) {
        echo floor($diff / 31536000000) . " year";
    } else if (floor($diff / 86400000)) {
        echo floor($diff / 2592000000) . " months";
    } else if (floor($diff / 86400000)) {
        echo floor($diff / 86400000) . " days";
    } else if (floor($diff / 3600000)) {
        echo floor($diff / 3600000) . " hours";
    } else if (floor($diff / 60000)) {
        echo floor($diff / 60000) . " minutes";
    } else {
        echo "now";
    }

}

dateDiff($NOW, $Time);
```

For `151048737944` it return: `4 year`

Comment: Why not simply using the DateTime class? (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: You do know that your JS code contains _no jQuery at all_ but only native JavaScript?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sometimes I forget this is not jQuery that wrote, because i always use `jquery`  then `javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DateTime diff function:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2015-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$yearsdifference = $interval->format('%y');
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Comment: got error `Call to a member function diff() on integer`

Comment: Try again, I promise you I'm getting this: `string '6' (length=1)` when I `var_dump($yearsdifference);`

Comment: Make sure ure calling right the construct of DateTime [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) right, you need to pass string to instanciate new DateTime object

Comment: It works with this format `2009-10-11` but i using `timestamp`

Comment: Convert [timestamp to DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimestamp.php) following the first example :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your timestamp `$Time` is correct? it prints the following date 1992-12-214 when used with `date("y-m-d")` can you make sure that it is correct?

Moreover, you should use `date_diff` in php rather than converting this javascript see here for manual [manual date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) or use this stackoverflow post to calculate the difference [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time)

see below updated code for your solution you are using wrong `since time` figures see below for the correct ones

```
<?php 
$NOW = strtotime("now");
$date = new DateTime('2017-11-01');

$Time = $date->getTimestamp();

function dateDiff($date1, $date2){
   $diff = abs($date1 - $date2);

  if (floor($diff / 31536000 )) {
    echo floor($diff / 31536000) . " year";
  } else if (floor($diff / 2592000 )) {
    echo floor($diff / 2592000 ) . " months";
  } else if (floor($diff / 86400  )) {
    echo floor($diff / 86400  ) . " days";
  } else if (floor($diff / 3600 )) {
    echo floor($diff / 3600 ) . " hours";
  } else if (floor($diff / 60 )) {
    echo floor($diff / 60 ) . " minutes";
  } else {
    echo "now";
  }

}
echo "difference between ".date('Y-m-d',$NOW)." and ".date("Y-m-d",$Time).'is <br /> ';
dateDiff($NOW, $Time);

?>
```

Comment: This should be a comment, consider adding an example to your answer :)

Comment: yeah but i recently received an email from moderator that i should not copy paste solution from other sites or stackoverflow but i should provide proper link to the actual solution if i am not providing custom solution. :( should i delete the post ?

Comment: You should address the error first and try to answer why does OP get the wrong date. Afterwards, you might suggest the date_diff function as a better way to address this case (and it's also a better practice as a programmer). In the suggestion you should use, for instance, the example code from the manual while relating to the OP code. (Just edit your answer, no need to remove it)

Comment: i updated the answer the above should print 11 days difference for you