# How to get Time ago format for a given date in PHP?

Tags: php

Suppose if a date is in the format

> 2018-10-10 16:24:52

How to get time ago format for this date as

> 2 days ago

..

If date format is 
`2018-09-10 16:24:52` The date format should be `1 month ago` 
and if `2017-10-10 16:24:52` The date format should be `1 year ago`

How to achieve this in PHP?

Comment: Another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915864/php-how-to-find-the-time-elapsed-since-a-date-time

Answer (score 0):

Try this library - https://github.com/jenssegers/date

From `README.md` -

> Get a human readable output (alias for diffForHumans):
>
> ```
> echo $date->ago(); // 5 days ago
> ```