# PHP Get file which is older than 1 day and where filename starts with "a"

Tags: php, grep, timestamp, shell-exec, unlink

### So what I want to do is:

Delete a file:

- If a filename in a directory starts with 'a' then check if it's older than 1 day.

OR

- If a filename in a directory starts with 'b' then check if it's older than 1 week.

Example:

afilename.jpg (timestamp says the file is 2 days old) -> Delete / unlink.

### What I tried so far:

```
<?php
// $files = preg_grep('~^a.*~', scandir("./uploads"));
// I want to combine line 1 & line 3 but I don't know how to do this.
$files = shell_exec('find ./uploads -mmin +1440');
$file = explode("\n",$files);
if(isset($file) && is_array($file))
{
    foreach($file as $val)
    {
        // @unlink($val);
        echo "found";
    }
}
?>
```

I hope it is clear what I want to do.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine file age using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757097/how-to-determine-file-age-using-php)

Comment: No. I want to check for 2 different ages. If the filename starts with 'a', I want to check if the file is older than 1 day. If the filename starts with 'b' I want to check if the file is older than one week.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code for checking for "starts with" & related logic. Use [filemtime](https://www.php.net/filemtime) to check the age. N.B. your `if(isset($file) && is_array($file))` is redundant, since `$file` is a result of `explode`. It will always be set and be an array, even if you feed an empty string to `explode`.

Comment: Line 1 checks if it starts with 'a'. How can I combine that with filemtime?

Comment: Why don't you just glob for `^[ab]` to get both types of files. Toss the shell_exec, not needed. In the loop, check for first character and `filemtime`, and take action if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Got it.

```
<?php
$dir = "./uploads/";

foreach (glob($dir."[ab]*") as $file) { 
    if (filemtime($file) < time() - 86400 && glob($dir."a*")) { 
        unlink($file);
    }
    if (filemtime($file) < time() - 604800 && glob($dir."b*")) { 
        unlink($file);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: That will work, however you will do a full directory read and pattern matching twice. It would be cheaper and (DRY) to read `[ab]*` and have a condition in one loop.

Comment: Like this? (i edited the answer)

Comment: Don't glob again, you already have the filelist! All you need is checking the first character of the filename: `$mtime = filemtime($file); if(basename($file)[0] === 'a' && $mtime < time() - 86400) ... `. And likewise for "b".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).